# Reply to address in Indy 10?

Tags: delphi, indy10

Since I upgraded to Indy10, I've noticed that the ReplyTo field (`Msg.ReplyTo[0].Address`) on received TIdMessage(s) seems to be getting filled in with the address from the Return-path header if an explicit reply to header isn't present. My expectation would be that the `Msg.ReplyTo.Count` should be zero if there's no reply-to header. What's going on here? Is this a bug? Design change? Something else? How can I tell whether the message has a separate reply-to address, or whether I should be replying to the address from the "from" field? Having it reply to the return-address seems to give a butchered version of my own email, not very useful.

My existing logic (that isn't working for messages with no reply-to address) looks like this:

```
if Msg.ReplyTo.Count>0 then
  FReplyTo := Msg.ReplyTo[0].Address
else
  FReplyTo := Msg.From.Address;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Having it reply to the return-address seems to give a butchered version of my own email"?

Comment: the header looks about like this...(which in and of itself is not unexpected)...but not what I expect to see as a reply-to address for an email TO me not FROM me. Return-path: <mydomain+caf_=myusername=mydomain.net@gmail.com>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When parsing an email, `TIdMessage.ReplyTo` looks at the `Reply-To` header first, and if empty/missing then looks at the `Return-Path` header.  If you want to know whether `Reply-To` by itself is blank/missing or not, you will have to look at `TIdMessage.Headers.Values['Reply-To']` manually.

Thinking about it more, and doing some research into how `Reply-To` and `Return-Path` actually work, it probably makes sense to remove `Return-Path` from the `TIdMessage.ReplyTo` property, so I have made that change now.

Comment: Thank you, the updated Indy code works much better at making it possible to actually reply to the sender :)